# MercadoPago Applications no devuelve credenciales de usuario

Tags: php, curl, mercadopago

Siguiendo la documentación de MercadoPago (https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/mp-applications/) llego al punto donde necesito obtener las credenciales del usuario.

Previamente se creó la aplicación y se le envió el e-mail a la persona de la que necesitamos la autorización.

Al momento de solicitar sus credenciales lo que MercadoPago devuelve es:

```
{"message":"The redirect_uri does not match the original","error":"invalid_grant","status":400,"cause":[]}
```

La URL es la misma que se cargó en la creación de la aplicación y el parámetro que se pasa. (http://mi-url)

```
$datos = array(
        'client_id' => [CLIENT_ID],
        'client_secret' => [CLIENT_SECRET],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => [CODIGO_OBTENIDO_DE_GET],
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://mi-url'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mercadopago.com/oauth/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($datos));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    var_dump($output);
```

Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: El mensaje de error te indica que la url donde se realizo la autenticación y en el que obtuviste el authorization code no es la misma a la que esta haciendo la consulta por el access_token, podrias empezar revisando ello.

Comment: Eso es lo raro. Está puesta la misma URL

Comment: Estas usando https ?

Comment: Estoy en modo local, por eso puse el CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER en false.

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales y este otro también! https://www.acamica.com/cursos/62/introduccion-a-la-api-de-mercadolibre Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Este error se da solamente cuando la `redirect_uri` de la aplicación no coincide con la enviada en el url donde el usuario ingresa.

Lo más probable es que te esté faltando una `/` al final o algún detalle similar, pero solo se da en este caso.

Ejemplo: Si en la aplicación configuraste en `redirect_url` http://mi-url/, pero en la url utilizas http://mi-url, esta va a fallar.

Toda la información de tu aplicación la podes ver ingresando al siguiente [link](https://applications.mercadopago.com.ar/list?platform=mp) y haciendo click en "*Details*" para ver o "*Edit*" para editar.