# Mercado Pago Connect "The redirect_uri does not match the original"

Tags: mercadopago

Saludos,

Estoy intentando de utilizar el api de mercado pago connect, pero tengo problemas para obtener las credenciales de mi usuario. Ya configure el url de mi aplicación en mercado pago, al redirigir al usuario a la pagina de mercado pago para que este ingrese sus credenciales, mercadopago envía correctamente el token de autorización a mi servidor node.js, pero ya en el con dicho token intento de solicitar las credenciales y siempre me muestra el mismo error:

```
{"name":"MercadoPagoError","message":"{\"message\":\"The redirect_uri does not match the original\",\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"status\":400,\"cause\":[]}","stack":"Error\n    at new MercadoPagoError (/user_code/node_modules/mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.js:16:16)\n    at Request._callback (/user_code/node_modules/mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.js:527:22)\n    at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/mercadopago/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/mercadopago/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/mercadopago/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)","statu
```

El código que utilizo del lado del servidor es el siguiente:

```
// Create the request
const mpCredentialsRequest = {
    "uri": "/oauth/token",
    "params": {
        "client_secret": ACCESS_TOKEN,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": authorizationCode,
        "redirect_uri": url
    },
    "authenticate": false
};

//Requesting the client credentials
mercadopago.post(mpCredentialsRequest).then(function(result) {

    console.log(`result.status = ${result.status}`);
    if(result.status == 200){
      const credentials = result.response;
      processCredentials(userId, credentials, req, res);
    }

}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.send(500, error);
});
```

En el url pongo el mismo que tengo configurado en mercado pago.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Esto ya se pregunto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46174/mercadopago-applications-no-devuelve-credenciales-de-usuario

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso el problema era el URL que tenia configurado, el cual en la configuración de mercadopago lo tenia con `https` y en mi código cliente utilizaba `http`, solo hice el cambio y funciono correctamente.